# Completing Learn About Configuration in the Sales Process

Tags: trailhead, cpq

I am using my developer org to complete this unit.

Here is the link: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/cpq-product-configuration/configuration-in-the-sales-process

I have created the bundle as per the hands-on exercise.

But I am not able to complete the challenge as getting error **We can't find a quote line record for the 'Printer High Capacity Tray' product for quote 'Q-00001**.

But the product *Printer High Capacity Tray* is not present in my developer org.

What I have missed in the process?

Comment: For this module, Have you signed up using a CPQ-enabled Developer Edition org?

Comment: No. I had a developer org which had Salesforce CPQ, using that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked after created CPQ-enabled Org using [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/cpqtrails) link provided in the trailhead.

The new org had the product and quote required to complete the training.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you've recently signed up for a special CPQ-enabled Developer Edition org, sign up for new one now. We're always adding new data. Also note that the Salesforce CPQ managed package expires after 90 days, so you may need a new org anyway.

Sign up for a free Developer Edition org with Salesforce CPQ.

Link: https://developer.salesforce.com/promotions/orgs/cpqtrails

Fill out the form. For Email, enter an active email address. For Username, enter a username that looks like an email address and is unique, but it doesn't need to be a valid email account (for example, yourname@cpq4ever.com).

After you fill out the form, click Sign me up. A confirmation message appears.
When you receive the activation email (this might take a few minutes), open it and click Verify Account.